# Why are Windows 10 crashes not getting reported to Microsoft?

Tags: windows, windows-10, crash, telemetry

I've been experiencing frequent Blue Screen of Death crashes on my Windows 10 PC, and the error message suggests the issue is the video driver. The exact nature of the problem isn't important to my question, but I want to make sure Microsoft and their partners get as much data about the problem as possible so they can hopefully fix it. However, whenever I use Problem Report Viewer to check the diagnostic data for recent crashes, it always says that Windows errors have a status of "Not Reported".

[image: Screenshot of Problem Report Viewer]

The list of problems in the above screenshot is somewhat short, because I recently reinstalled Windows in an attempt to fix my problems. However, before the reinstall, I would often see several weeks worth of unexpected shutdown errors listed here, all with a status of "Not reported".

My question is, why are these reports not getting sent? Can I manually send this data to Microsoft or another hardware vendor somehow? Is there a setting in Windows that might be affecting this?

***Edit Sept 11, 2020:***

To further confuse things, I just noticed that when I view the unexpected shutdown events in Diagnostic Data Viewer, it says "Status: Report sent". However, the Problem Report Viewer still says "Not reported" for the same event. Does that mean that one of these two statuses is incorrect? Or is this two different reporting pipelines?

[image: Diagnostic Data Viewer]

[image: Problem Report Viewer, 2nd Screenshot]

Comment: @Ramhound these are blue-screen-of-death computer crashes. It is different from when an application crashes and the OS keeps running. There is no opportunity to select anything or interact in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been able to confirm this 100%, but based on recent observations I believe these crash reports are tied to the "Optional diagnostic data" option in the  "Diagnostics & Feedback" settings.

[image: Optional diagnostic data setting]

A few days ago I changed this setting from "Required diagnostic data" to "Optional diagnostic data", and crashes that have occurred since then are now showing as "Report sent" in the Problem Reports Viewer.

[image: Recent unexpected shutdowns reported]

Comment: Is there a way to send the reports without enabling "Send info about websites you browse"?  Is there a way to send previous reports?